# while zooming the browser i want particular iframe not to be zoom in HTMl

Tags: html, zooming

while zooming the browser i want particular iframe not to be zoom in HTMl.Can I zoom the page without zooming the iframe.In below example i want to zoom the page rest of iframe content.Is that possible??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
div>adsfa</div>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

does this answer help - [How to prevent an iframe from re-sizing when zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339561/3768252)? A JavaScript solution is suggested: you need to detect the browser zoom level and control the zoom of the iframe yourself.